# Python & WNCK: Get data from a window

Tags: python, ubuntu, process, wnck

I have a program executing through **wine** in **Ubuntu 13**, this program has its own GUI and there is some data on this program like in this picture:

[image: Tables per room]

My intention is (using **Python**) get this window, and try to obtain this data from it.

Right now I'm trying using **wnsck**:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck

Gtk.init([])
screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update()

all_windows = screen.get_windows()  # First I get all windows

# Then I search my window 
my_window = all_windows[-1]  # Let's supose it's the last window

# I'm trying to do things like
my_window.get_data()  
my_window.steal_data()
# ... and many others methods I saw could be what I'm looking for
```

When I try to get some data as I said above I allways get:

```
RuntimeError: Data access methods are unsupported. Use normal Python attributes instead
```

- Does anybody if it's possible to get process data with *wnck* ?
- Does anybody knows another way to achieve what I'm trying ?

**I'm trying to get some values displayed on the window**

*I know there are some libraries for windows, but I'm interested doing this in Ubuntu*

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "get data"?  Do you want a screenshot or actual data from the program?

Comment: @hazzey data from the program if It's possible

Comment: If the program that you are trying to get data from doesn't have ways to get the the data that you are looking for, you will most likely have to read the data from memory (This is not easy).